# Html2Canvas and Canvas2Image not work on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, html2canvas

I have this simple code to save html as image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#save').click(function () {
            var elem = $('#element').get(0);
            var leba = "600";
            var ting = "400";
            var type = "bmp";
            var name = "temp"
            html2canvas(elem).then(function (canvas) {
                var cWidth = canvas.width;
                var cHeight = canvas.height;
                var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, cWidth, cHeight);
                $('#preview').after(img);
                Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, leba, ting, type, name);

            })
        })
    </script>
    <div id="element"
        style="width: 600px; height: 450px; background-color: aquamarine; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center">
        <h1>Screenshot</h1>
        <input type="text" style="background-color: aliceblue; border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; color: #333333">
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <button id="save">Salva</button>
        <p id="preview"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have a preview of the screenshot and save it on click, but when I click nothing happens.

The three files containing the three scripts are correctly loaded, I'm using visual studio code and the links are correct, but despite the attempts, I can't get the image.

I also tried to put the js links directly, but without success, I moved the scripts directly into the HTML tag (I know it's useless), but my page doesn't give any results.

Answer (score 0):

For saving the canvas as image you can go through the below change. I dont think so, that you need a library to save the file.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#element")).then(function (canvas) {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = dataURL;
    a.download = 'untitled.jpeg';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
```

And for the complete reference you can visit the CodePen link added below

https://codepen.io/mukeshmohan/pen/ymvQjV

And its recommended to wrap your code inside a document ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // your script goes here
});
```

which will make the jquery to wait till the dom rendering completes, that allows a safe and clean event handling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a

```js
$( document ).ready()
```

block

Take a look [here](https://repl.it/repls/PositiveBossyGui)